# JS non-inline version of console.collapsedGroup

Tags: javascript, console.log

Is there a way to use `console.groupCollapsed()` such that the inner elements maintain any custom styling?

Comment: I think you mean .groupCollapsed()?

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan yes